# Xamarin removing CollectionView children

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've got a problem with not refreshing GUI elements in the Xamarin's `CollectionView`.

The `ObservableCollection` **Items** binded to the `CollectionView` is cleared and filled with new elements during the *RefreshingEvent* but on the screen the old `StackLayout`s are shown.

The reason is that the `SingleItem` controls are not removed/deleted on `Items.Clear()` - **how to do it**?

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collection"
       ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
       SelectionMode="None">
       <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                  <StackLayout>
                       <controls:SingleItem/>
                       <Grid BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="5" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                  </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
       </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

C# - nothing "unusual" and this works alright (on breakpoints):

```
void RefreshCommand()
{
    List<Item> items = null;
    items = GetItems();
    if (items != null)
    {
        Items.Clear();
        foreach (var item in items)
            Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Wait, before You go forward, because below I wrote my "idea" how to solve it.

The problem is that I found no "Clear" or "Remove" method of GUI `AllChildren` - which is a internal member of `Element`:

```
void RefreshCommand(Action clearCollectionView)
{
    List<Item> items = null;
    items = GetItems();
    if (items != null)
    {
        Items.Clear();
        cleacCollectionView.Invoke();
        foreach (var item in items)
            Items.Add(item);
    }
}
// page.xaml.cs:
...
        BindingContext = new Model(() => ???);
...
```

Comment: Could you add all of the c# code related to `Items` collection?

Comment: Found a workaround :) but still this may be usefull for others I will leave this topic and watch it for a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the `Grid` like this and bind the `ObservableCollection` data to the label instead of using the `<controls:SingleItem/>`

```
  <CollectionView  x:Name="Collection"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="5" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="End">
                       
                        <Label
                                Text="{Binding itemName}"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                x:Name="labelname" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                       
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```